# Writing to multiple files in a loop gives identical files

Tags: python, file, loops, odeint

Attempting to solve some equations with differing initial conditions produced through a loop.

I want to obtain multiple files each representing the different initial conditions due to the 'while' loop, but every file is the same, the data won't change. Can't see where I have gone wrong.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint

P = 0      # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy percent  (per day)

# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
     Si = y[0]
     Zi = y[1]
     Ri = y[2]
     # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
     f0 = P - B*Si*Zi - d*Si
     f1 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
     f2 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
     return [f0, f1, f2]

Si0 = 50
Zi0 = 20
Ri0= 20

for i in range(20):   
    while Zi0 < 105:
        Zi0 += 5
        y0=[Si0,Zi0,Ri0]
        print(Zi0)


        y = odeint(f, y0, [k*500 for k in range(40)], mxstep=1000)


    print('\n'.join(','.join('%+13.5f'%x for x in row) for row in \
    y),file=open("test_"+str(i)+".txt", "a"))
```

Comment: What is some sample output?

Comment: The Zi value (which has differing initial conditions) is constantly: 105,156,158,159... for all 20 files

Comment: Can you put a `print(y)` at the top of your `f` function? And then show us what comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that you aren't resetting Zi0. So the first time in the for loop it's doing the while loop until Zi0 is 105. Then the second for loop starts and Zi0 is already 105, so it's skipping the while loop and prints, and continues to skip and print for the rest of the for loop.

Not completely sure what you want to change every for loop, so can't help you more... sorry.

Comment: Oh right, how could I output to a file everytime Zi0 changes? Is it my placement of the file writer that is wrong?

Comment: You want to output everytime Zi0 changes? get rid of the 'while Zi0 < 105'. Then it will increment Zi0 by 5 and print everything every time.

Comment: But in that case, won't Zi0 increase until infinity? I wanted the integration to stop once Zi0 reaches 105.

Comment: it will continue for 21 cycles, because it's in the for loop.
Isn't that why you pu the for loop there in the first place?

Comment: The for loop was just to name the different output files in the end; test0, test1 etc

Comment: The for loop works for that, yes. Still you don't actually need the while loop for anything.